# Computing the number from array's elements in assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

I read a number from keyboard and stored it in an array called buf. I also have the length of the array in the len variable.

I am trying now to compute the number from that array. My code is this:

```
   xor si, si
   xor bx, bx ; made them 0 
   start_for:
    cmp si, len
    je end_for
    mul bx, 10 ; I think here is the problem! 
    mov al, buff[si]  
    sub al, '0'
    add bx, ax
    inc si
    jmp start_for

   end_for:
```

What is the problem?

I noticed on debug that the line 'mul bx, 10' has no effect.

Comment: AS is, your number can only grow to 65535 before overflowing - is that the problem you are experiencing?  Does you code work for smaller numbers?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for any number of entries in the array.

Comment: The ah problem in the answer below is also a good tip.

Answer (score 3):

In the line `add bx, ax`, it appears that the upper byte `ah` is not yet defined.  I recommend setting `ax` or `ah` to `0`.

Also, i86 might not put the 'mul' product where you think.  The product may be in DX:AX even with a BX operand.  Recommend swapping use of AX and BX in your code.  Let AX be your final product and bx your single digit value.

Comment: I defined it and it still doesn't work. It only computes the sum of the elements, the multiplication of bx has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I was incorrectly using the MUL instruction.
Modified the program and it works:

```
xor si, si
xor ax, ax        

   start_for:
    cmp si, len
    je end_for 
    mov bx, 10
    mul bx ; This means AX = AX * BX (for 8 bit operands)
    mov bh, 0 
    mov bl, buff[si]  
    sub bl, '0'
    add ax, bx
    inc si
    jmp start_for

   end_for:
```

AX and BX registers changed their meaning. AX will store the number and BX is used only for MUL.